# JavaMailSender.send(msg) Method Fails to Successfully Terminate Connection With Internal SMTP Server in Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, smtp, timeout

I am trying to create a 'helloworld' application with Java 17, Spring Boot 3.1 and Maven 4.0 that can send emails with a simple text file attachment. I am using the `JavaMailSender` class provided by Jakarta Mail (2.1.1) from the `spring-boot-starter-mail` artifact. I have successfully managed to create the `EmailSender` class, shown below:

```java
@Component
public class EmailSender {

    private String emailFrom = "Email 1";
    private String emailTo = "Email 2";
    private String emailCc = "Email 2";

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public int send(String message, String title, File file) throws MessagingException {

        MimeMessage msg = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true);

        helper.setFrom(emailFrom);
        helper.setCc(emailCc);
        helper.setSubject(title);
        helper.setTo(emailTo);
        if (file != null) {
            helper.addAttachment("Test", file);
        }
        helper.setText(message, false);
        try {
            javaMailSender.send(msg);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t.toString());
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Using the following properties in application.properties, this method works, and sends emails using Gmails SMTP server:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=somone@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=an app password
```

However, when I change `spring.mail.host=smtp.internal-organization-server`, my problem arises. The  `send` method in the `EmailSender` class hangs on the `javaMailSender.send(msg)` line for about 2 minutes. This is the debugging output when I run my `testSendEmail()` method:

```
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp-internal-organization-server", port: 25

... Everything that is expected ...

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Test

This is the first line of the file
This is the second and last line in file
------=_Part_0_number.number--
.
```

Despite the debugging input raising no errors and ending with the `.\n` characters as expected, the connection with the SMTP server does not terminate for around 2 minutes, and then this error is thrown:

```
RSET
DEBUG SMTP: EOF: [EOF]
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW: 
org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 421 4.4.2 internal-server-name Error: timeout exceeded
```

I tried every combination of properties in the application properties file to get it to work, including changing the port number, connection type, and the authentication and tls protocols, but still had the same issue. Finally, while developing a different feature, I found that the `javaMailSender.send(msg)` method works **if and only if** I add **all** of the following dependencies the to my pom.xml file:

```xml
        <!-- Oauth 2 --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Webflux-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring Doc--> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Actuator-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Removing any one of them causes the `send` method to start hanging again. UPDATE: In addition, this only allows methods called by J-Unit tests to send emails correctly. When the main method of a different application calls the same `send` method in the `EmailNotifier` class, it hangs and fails to terminate once again. I have not found dependencies that cause the connection to successfully terminate in this case.

Here is my full pom.xml file for reference:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.setup</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>helloworld</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot 3.1</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Other dependencies required to make Email Service work with Internal SMTP Server. Project compiles without them-->

        <!-- Oauth 2 --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Webflux-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring Doc--> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Actuator-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- End of email dependencies -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My two questions can be summarized as thus:

1. What in these seemingly unrelated dependencies might cause the connection to an internal SMTP server to successfully terminate, when without them it does not? UPDATE: Why would these dependencies only affect methods ran as J-Unit tests?
2. What might be causing this issue, given that it does not arise with Gmail's SMTP server? I suspect it is something to do with the local SMTP server, but have had no experience configuring one.

Thank you!